# opensnitch: changing a "process.path" rule to match command args

Tags: security, configuration, firewall

#### Opensnitch intro

[opensnitch](https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch) is an open-source security tool modeled after the MAC OS-X [`littlesnitch`](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) app.

I've been using Gustavo Iniguez Goya's fork of opensnitch (which is a big improvement over the original great pioneering work by Simone Margaritelli) on my desktop to limit outgoing connections based on rules. The goal is to beef-up outgoing network security, for example to catch malware or limit some "phone-home" apps from talking to the outside world.

#### Configuration/rules

The default rules which drive opensnitch, are created under `/etc/opensnitchd/rules` are stored as `*.json` files, one file per rule. When I use the UI to add a rule, a new `*.json` rule file gets created.

#### Example of a rule (trimmed down for brevity):

```
{
  "name": "allow-always-simple-usrbinpython",
  "enabled": true,
  "action": "allow",
  "duration": "always",
  "operator": {
    "type": "simple",
    "operand": "process.path",
    "data": "/usr/bin/python",
  }
}
```

#### Problem

These rules may be too coarse when setting them from the UI. e.g. when I allow a certain script I wrote to talk to the outside world, and that executable just happens to be written in `python` selecting the <kbd>executable</kbd> option and clicking <kbd>Allow</kbd>, I inadvertently allow *any* `python` script to talk to the outside world.

Searching the web, I was able to find a [nice overview of opensnich](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/03/opensnitch-linux-application-firewall.html) which is missing the detail of how to specify conjunctive rules directly in `*.json` and match the full command line, with examples.

#### Questions:

- Is it possible to limit such rule and allow running only a **certain executable script** (1st arg to `/usr/bin/python`) ?
- More generally: what would be the syntax, with an example, for an ***`AND` conjunction*** in the rule, and a ***clause for a regex-match vs. other arguments*** of the command line or remote IP-addresses, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to limit such rule and allow running only a certain executable script (1st arg to /usr/bin/python) ?

You can select the option "from this command line" to filter by the whole command.

[image]

> More generally: what would be the syntax, with an example, for an AND conjunction in the rule, and a clause for a regex-match vs. other arguments of the command line or remote IP-addresses, or both?

take a look at the documentation (maybe you already did... but just in case):

https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch/wiki/Rules
https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch/wiki/Rules-editor

For example, if you wanted to filter by a particular (python) script:

[x] From this command line: "`.*/usr/bin/dnsping.*`"

[image]

(By the way, we finally are contributing to the original repo, so you can use latest releases from there)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. Also for all your work on `opensnitch`.  I've since learned that I can edit rules directly from the UI (`opensnitch-ui`) by clicking on `rules`, then double clicking on the rule-name, then clicking on the little white square (edit) icon right next to the `<` back icon.  This multi-step sequence was not obvious to me. Perhaps a more intuitive behavior is: double-clicking anywhere on the rule-line goes directly to the edit screen for that rule, and the edit screen has a delete-rule button in it as well (maybe that's the meaning of `[<x reset]`? not obvious).

Comment: I agree arielf, we've discussed a few weeks ago precisely to change that behaviour :) We'll change it soon.